# Create multiple test scenarios for a method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, xunit

I'm studying unit tests in dotnet and I have a doubt about the amount of scenarios that is acceptable to be done.

Should I make just one test scenario for my method or should I create several scenarios, store them in a list and iterate them in the Act part, comparing the method's return with the expected response that is already in the list?

I don't know if it would be a good practice to create a list with possible scenarios and their respective results, if anything different from what is expected is returned, which is already stored in the list, then it would be a failure to respond.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can say from my experience is that you should keep it simple and you should avoid doing logic in your test.

I can really recommend the [best practices provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#best-practices).

Comment: Basically what I wanted to know is exactly what is being described in this part here: [Avoid logic in tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#avoid-logic-in-tests)

The problem is that I'm testing the validation of a class, so in my Theory I should instantiate several versions of the same class. I'll take a look to see if this is possible or what the appropriate alternative is. 

Many thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know,
You should create unit test for successful scenario and catch the exceptions if the app throws excp.

Smhth like that:

```
public async Task Func_Success()
public async Task Func_NotFound()
public async Task Func_Conflict()
```

I think unit test should be simple and coverage lines.